# Tutorials or Documentation on SPServices

Tags: jquery, spservices

Anyone provide the links for the code snippets for jquery spservices .i can't found the examples on spservices.Am eager to learn the basics in spsservices.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [documentation](https://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) of the library. There are some great quick-start guide and examples there.

Since it is not good to have only a line of answer, then you could also check this [link](http://sympmarc.com/2013/02/15/spservices-stories-7-example-uses-of-spservices-javascript-and-sharepoint/) for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Complete documentation of the SPServices library can be found on [official site](https://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Also you can refer this external sites for small demos or example:

[Read list or document library items using jQuery SPServices in SharePoint 2013](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/read-list-or-document-library-items-using-jquery-spservices-in-20779.aspx)

[Retrieve List items from SharePoint 2013 based on ID column using CAML Query](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/retrieve-list-items-from-sharepoint-2013-based-on-id-column-20774.aspx)

[SPServices Cascading Dropdowns](http://www.bentedder.com/sharepoint-sketches-spservices-cascading-dropdowns/)